# Как запустить selenium webdriver на vps?

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, selenium, centos7

Есть файл index.js, который с помощью selenium работает с браузером. Он должен в консоли отображать данные, которые спарсил, но сейчас он просто зависает. Тоесть скрипт запускается, но не может спарсить данные, потому что это VPS и там нет графического интерфейса. На винде всё норм и данные в массиве есть.

**Настройка webdrivera в нём:**

```
const options = new Options()
options.addArguments('--no-sandbox')
options.addArguments('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

let webdriver = new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').setChromeOptions(options).build()
```

**Место, где скрипт перестаёт отвечать:**

```
console.log('Этот консоль лог покажется')
await webdriver.get('https://ru.wikipedia.org') // url рандомный
console.log('А этот нет')
```

Мне нужно запустить его на vps сервере. Как мне этого добиться?
Я пытался это сделать, используя xvfb, но у меня не получилось.

**Вот что я пытался сделать:**

```
npm install xvfb -g
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 640x480x24 -fbdir /var/tmp&
export DISPLAY=localhost:1.0
DISPLAY=localhost:1.0 node index.js
```

p.s

Версии webdriver и хрома 98.0.4758.48, операционная система CentOS 7.

Comment: А зачем здесь вообще Xvfb? Хром вполне способен работать в headless-режиме без какой-либо графики

Comment: в headless-режиме он даже на винде ничего не парсит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот решение, если кому вдруг понадобится

```
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x24 & export DISPLAY=:1
node index.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо не забыть выполнить (версию, наверное, надо убрать из команды):

```
npm install -g selenium-standalone@7.1.0 && selenium-standalone install
```

После этого можно запускать тесты.

Comment: К сожалению не помогло ( 
После строчки: await webdriver.get('https://ru.wikipedia.org') скрипт не отвечает